# When styling using Material-UI with React, why do some component's classname have different numbers appended to it?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components, makestyles

For example, if you create a makeStyles variable for a component (e.g. TableRow) and that component is called multiple times by a parent component (Table), each TableRow gets class names like “.mui-make-styles-column244” and “.mui-make-styles-column331”.

Is there a reason for this?

Can't tell if this number scheme is an optimization or if it indicates that I should be optimizing how I organize my styles.

Comment: If you are getting more than one class name for the same call to `makeStyles` then you are most likely using it incorrectly. Please post an example of your code where you see this behavior -- preferably along with a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing the behavior.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Actually in the process of making the code sandbox, I realized my issue. I was calling makeStyles in each row component rather than calling it once. Once I refactored this, performance improved significantly. Thanks a lot!